# NSDate to String conversion and display in the UILabel

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get a string from NSDate object type and display it in a label.
Here is the code I am using,

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
//[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSDate *datey = [dateFormatter dateFromString:selectedDate];
NSString *labelData = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datey];
dateLabel.Text = labelData;
```

where selectedDate is a String containing date in yyyy-mm-dd format.
The label is not showing up the date. But if I try giving it a string like @"someblah", it is displaying. Where am I going wrong??
Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to convert custom timestamp to different format in Objective-C iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823129/need-to-convert-custom-timestamp-to-different-format-in-objective-c-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `dateLabel.Text` should be `dateLabel.text`.

So you start with a date string, convert it to a date, and then convert it back to a string using the same formatter.  Isn't it easier to use:

```
dateLabel.text = selectedDate;
```

In all likelihood you are trying to create an NSDate using a date string that is inconsistent with the format.  For example, if the format is `@"yyyy-MM-dd"` but your selectedDate differs from that format then the formatter won't return a NSDate.  You can avoid this by setting the DateFormat to be correct for the selectedDate and then, once parsed, change the DateFormat for the desired output.  Or use two `NSDateFormatter` instances.

Comment: i dont know why..it is still not working!! :( well, I want to display the date in a different format, so i had to convert it to NSDate, get my desired format and print.

Comment: when i try to display dateLabel.text = selectedDate, it works!! but when i am trying to change the format and display..it doesnt show anything..

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a specific format instead of `NSDateFormatLongStyle`, for example

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

I found this answer in 2 seconds using google.. (Yes thats a hint)

Comment: I missed the casing bug of the .text property. But how did you solve the date parsing problem?

Comment: my selecteddate was in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" and I was trying to parse it using NSDateFormatterLongStyle, which is why it didnt return a NSDate. When I changed the formatter to "yyyy-mm-dd", It returned the NSDate and I could happily convert it to format I wanted to display in my label. :)